# Accessing array within an array the list of JSON obects in React native? : [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, google-directions-api

I am attempting fetching data from Google Directions and i want to access the transit_details section of this JSON response. Here is a sample of the response, which is succesful during fetch. (pardon for this long sample) but i want to get the values from transit_details, which is an object within the arrays of steps and legs.

this is the actual object representation response that i get, and in accordance to the google directions documentation that can be found here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/ under transit and i am successful on getting the response shown below: 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
    Object {
  "geocoded_waypoints": Array [
    Object {
      "geocoder_status": "OK",
      "place_id": "ChIJ2YDFT9zweUgRgt5Tws6n3hs",
      "types": Array [
        "premise",
      ],
    },
    Object {
      "geocoder_status": "OK",
      "place_id": "ChIJW2PCihXxeUgRRWgA9kOzpjY",
      "types": Array [
        "establishment",
        "food",
        "lodging",
        "point_of_interest",
        "restaurant",
      ],
    },
  ],
  "routes": Array [
    Object {
      "bounds": Object {
        "northeast": Object {
          "lat": 52.9242042,
          "lng": -1.466251,
        },
        "southwest": Object {
          "lat": 52.9004767,
          "lng": -1.4801554,
        },
      },
      "copyrights": "Map data ©2018 Google",
      "legs": Array [
        Object {
          "arrival_time": Object {
            "text": "9:21am",
            "time_zone": "Europe/London",
            "value": 1524558107,
          },
          "departure_time": Object {
            "text": "8:56am",
            "time_zone": "Europe/London",
            "value": 1524556589,
          },
          "distance": Object {
            "text": "3.4 km",
            "value": 3407,
          },
          "duration": Object {
            "text": "25 mins",
            "value": 1518,
          },
          "end_address": "Full St, Derby DE1 3AF, UK",
          "end_location": Object {
            "lat": 52.9242042,
            "lng": -1.4756769,
          },
          "start_address": "50 Chatham St, Derby DE23 8TH, UK",
          "start_location": Object {
            "lat": 52.9004767,
            "lng": -1.480144,
          },
          "steps": Array [
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
                "text": "0.2 km",
                "value": 175,
              },
              "duration": Object {
                "text": "2 mins",
                "value": 123,
              },
              "end_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.900963,
                "lng": -1.478217,
              },
              "html_instructions": "Walk to Randolph Road",
              "polyline": Object {
                "points": "_c{aIza`Hm@BEyHC_Ag@S?H",
              },
              "start_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.9004767,
                "lng": -1.480144,
              },
              "steps": Array [
                Object {
                  "distance": Object {
                    "text": "26 m",
                    "value": 26,
                  },
                  "duration": Object {
                    "text": "1 min",
                    "value": 18,
                  },
                  "end_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.9007148,
                    "lng": -1.4801554,
                  },
                  "html_instructions": "Head <b>north</b> on <b>Chatham St</b> toward <b>Randolph Rd</b>",
                  "polyline": Object {
                    "points": "_c{aIza`Hm@B",
                  },
                  "start_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.9004767,
                    "lng": -1.480144,
                  },
                  "travel_mode": "WALKING",
                },
                Object {
                  "distance": Object {
                    "text": "0.1 km",
                    "value": 126,
                  },
                  "duration": Object {
                    "text": "1 min",
                    "value": 88,
                  },
                  "end_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.9007561,
                    "lng": -1.4782714,
                  },
                  "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Randolph Rd</b>",
                  "maneuver": "turn-right",
                  "polyline": Object {
                    "points": "md{aI~a`HEyHC_A",
                  },
                  "start_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.9007148,
                    "lng": -1.4801554,
                  },
                  "travel_mode": "WALKING",
                },
                Object {
                  "distance": Object {
                    "text": "23 m",
                    "value": 23,
                  },
                  "duration": Object {
                    "text": "1 min",
                    "value": 17,
                  },
                  "end_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.900963,
                    "lng": -1.478217,
                  },
                  "html_instructions": "Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>St Thomas Rd</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Destination will be on the left</div>",
                  "maneuver": "turn-left",
                  "polyline": Object {
                    "points": "wd{aIdv_Hg@S?H",
                  },
                  "start_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.9007561,
                    "lng": -1.4782714,
                  },
                  "travel_mode": "WALKING",
                },
              ],
              "travel_mode": "WALKING",
            },
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
                "text": "2.5 km",
                "value": 2460,
              },
              "duration": Object {
                "text": "15 mins",
                "value": 900,
              },
              "end_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.91829079999999,
                "lng": -1.4748049,
              },
              "html_instructions": "Bus towards Derby",
              "polyline": Object {
                "points": "_f{aIzu_HsPw@eHgW_IkOmHcPoLiNgKxQwHvL{LxKuK`G",
              },
              "start_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.900963,
                "lng": -1.478217,
              },
              "transit_details": Object {
                "arrival_stop": Object {
                  "location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.91829079999999,
                    "lng": -1.4748049,
                  },
                  "name": "Osmaston Road (Stop A8)",
                },
                "arrival_time": Object {
                  "text": "9:13am",
                  "time_zone": "Europe/London",
                  "value": 1524557580,
                },
                "departure_stop": Object {
                  "location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.900963,
                    "lng": -1.478217,
                  },
                  "name": "Randolph Road",
                },
                "departure_time": Object {
                  "text": "8:58am",
                  "time_zone": "Europe/London",
                  "value": 1524556715,
                },
                "headsign": "Derby",
                "line": Object {
                  "agencies": Array [
                    Object {
                      "name": "Arriva Midlands",
                      "url": "http://www.traveline.info/",
                    },
                  ],
                  "color": "#11416d",
                  "name": "Sapphire 38",
                  "text_color": "#ffffff",
                  "vehicle": Object {
                    "icon": "//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus2.png",
                    "name": "Bus",
                    "type": "BUS",
                  },
                },
                "num_stops": 9,
              },
              "travel_mode": "TRANSIT",
            },
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
```

The code below is my attempt to do this.

start of the code.. states

```
export default class Whereto extends Component<{}> {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null,
        travelinfo : []

        }
    }

fetchDirections = () => {
    var apiDirectionskey = '';
    //const {location} = this.state;
    const {latitude} = this.state;
    const {longitude} = this.state;
    const {goingto} = this.state;



fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&destination=' + goingto + '&mode=transit&transit_mode=bus&key=' + apiDirectionskey)
            .then((resdirections) => resdirections.json())
            .then((responseJson4) => {
                //console.log(responseJson3);
                var info = responseJson4.routes[0].legs.steps.transit_details.arrival_stop.location.lat;
                console.log(info);

            });
    }
```

my other attempts where:

```
var info = responseJson4.routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].transit_details.arrival_stop.location.lat;
var info = responseJson4.routes.legs.steps.transit_details.arrival_stop.location.lat;
var info = responseJson4.routes[0].legs[1].steps.transit_details.arrival_stop.location.lat;
```

and the reason my fetch call is inside a function is because, my render /view section has a text input and a button for the fetchdirection function

```
render(){

        return(

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Mainlogo/>
                <TextInput style={styles.boxInput} underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' placeholder="Going To?"
                           underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                           onChangeText={(dest) => this.setState({goingto : dest})}
                />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.fetchDirections.bind(this)}>
                    <Text style={styles.textButton}> Go {this.props.type}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>  ... truncated from a larger code
```

I am very new to this and any pointers on how to do this properly would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
            var info = responseJson3.routes[0];
            console.log(info);
```

results to this:

```
10:46:28
Object {
  "bounds": Object {
    "northeast": Object {
      "lat": 52.9242042,
      "lng": -1.466251,
    },
    "southwest": Object {
      "lat": 52.90047759999999,
      "lng": -1.4801554,
    },
  },
  "copyrights": "Map data ©2018 Google",
  "legs": Array [
    Object {
      "arrival_time": Object {
        "text": "11:17am",
        "time_zone": "Europe/London",
        "value": 1524565078,
      },
      "departure_time": Object {
        "text": "10:48am",
        "time_zone": "Europe/London",
        "value": 1524563326,
      },
      "distance": Object {
        "text": "3.8 km",
        "value": 3796,
      },
      "duration": Object {
        "text": "29 mins",
        "value": 1752,
      },
      "end_address": "Full St, Derby DE1 3AF, UK",
      "end_location": Object {
        "lat": 52.9242042,
        "lng": -1.4756769,
      },
      "start_address": "50 Chatham St, Derby DE23 8TH, UK",
      "start_location": Object {
        "lat": 52.90047759999999,
        "lng": -1.480144,
      },
      "steps": Array [
        Object {
          "distance": Object {
            "text": "0.2 km",
            "value": 175,
          },
          "duration": Object {
            "text": "2 mins",
            "value": 123,
          },
          "end_location": Object {
            "lat": 52.900963,
            "lng": -1.478217,
          },
          "html_instructions": "Walk to Randolph Road",
          "polyline": Object {
            "points": "_c{aIza`Hm@BEyHC_Ag@S?H",
          },
          "start_location": Object {
            "lat": 52.90047759999999,
            "lng": -1.480144,
          },
          "steps": Array [
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
                "text": "26 m",
                "value": 26,
              },
              "duration": Object {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 18,
              },
              "end_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.9007148,
                "lng": -1.4801554,
              },
              "html_instructions": "Head <b>north</b> on <b>Chatham St</b> toward <b>Randolph Rd</b>",
              "polyline": Object {
                "points": "_c{aIza`Hm@B",
              },
              "start_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.90047759999999,
                "lng": -1.480144,
              },
              "travel_mode": "WALKING",
            },
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
                "text": "0.1 km",
                "value": 126,
              },
              "duration": Object {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 88,
              },
              "end_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.9007561,
                "lng": -1.4782714,
              },
              "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Randolph Rd</b>",
              "maneuver": "turn-right",
              "polyline": Object {
                "points": "md{aI~a`HEyHC_A",
              },
              "start_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.9007148,
                "lng": -1.4801554,
              },
              "travel_mode": "WALKING",
            },
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
                "text": "23 m",
                "value": 23,
              },
              "duration": Object {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 17,
              },
              "end_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.900963,
                "lng": -1.478217,
              },
              "html_instructions": "Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>St Thomas Rd</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Destination will be on the left</div>",
              "maneuver": "turn-left",
              "polyline": Object {
                "points": "wd{aIdv_Hg@S?H",
              },
              "start_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.9007561,
                "lng": -1.4782714,
              },
              "travel_mode": "WALKING",
            },
          ],
          "travel_mode": "WALKING",
        },
        Object {
          "distance": Object {
            "text": "3.1 km",
            "value": 3129,
          },
          "duration": Object {
            "text": "20 mins",
            "value": 1200,
          },
          "end_location": Object {
            "lat": 52.92222599999999,
            "lng": -1.471283,
          },
          "html_instructions": "Bus towards Derby",
          "polyline": Object {
            "points": "_f{aIzu_HsPw@eHgW_IkOmHcPoLiNgKxQwHvL{LxKuK`G{AqEJoPcU`A",
          },
          "start_location": Object {
            "lat": 52.900963,
            "lng": -1.478217,
          },
          "transit_details": Object {
            "arrival_stop": Object {
              "location": Object {
                "lat": 52.92222599999999,
                "lng": -1.471283,
              },
              "name": "Bus Station (Bay 19)",
            },
            "arrival_time": Object {
              "text": "11:12am",
              "time_zone": "Europe/London",
              "value": 1524564720,
            },
            "departure_stop": Object {
              "location": Object {
                "lat": 52.900963,
                "lng": -1.478217,
              },
              "name": "Randolph Road",
            },
            "departure_time": Object {
              "text": "10:50am",
              "time_zone": "Europe/London",
              "value": 1524563452,
            },
            "headsign": "Derby",
            "line": Object {
              "agencies": Array [
                Object {
                  "name": "Arriva Midlands",
                  "url": "http://www.traveline.info/",
                },
              ],
              "color": "#11416d",
              "name": "Sapphire 38",
              "text_color": "#ffffff",
              "vehicle": Object {
                "icon": "//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus2.png",
                "name": "Bus",
                "type": "BUS",
              },
            },
            "num_stops": 12,
          },
          "travel_mode": "TRANSIT",
        },
        Object {
          "distance": Object {
            "text": "0.5 km",
            "value": 492,
          },
          "duration": Object {
            "text": "6 mins",
            "value": 368,
          },
          "end_location": Object {
            "lat": 52.9242042,
            "lng": -1.4756769,
          },
          "html_instructions": "Walk to Full St, Derby DE1 3AF, UK",
          "polyline": Object {
            "points": "}j_bInj~GEJlAjCt@rAi@dCCFQz@Yv@a@t@Wb@IJGFUREAAAA?A@A?A?A?C@CDA??@CBAFA@?@AF[VGLiAl@MFMHCICCCACAG@GDCFAFKFIDIFE@OPONMLa@h@?@",
          },
          "start_location": Object {
            "lat": 52.92222599999999,
            "lng": -1.471283,
          },
          "steps": Array [
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
                "text": "0.1 km",
                "value": 105,
              },
              "duration": Object {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 80,
              },
              "end_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.9216,
                "lng": -1.4724555,
              },
              "html_instructions": "Head <b>southwest</b> toward <b>Morledge</b>",
              "polyline": Object {
                "points": "}j_bInj~GEJlAjCt@rA",
              },
              "start_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.92222599999999,
                "lng": -1.471283,
              },
              "travel_mode": "WALKING",
            },
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
                "text": "0.2 km",
                "value": 171,
              },
              "duration": Object {
                "text": "2 mins",
                "value": 117,
              },
              "end_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.922543,
                "lng": -1.4743966,
              },
              "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Morledge</b>",
              "maneuver": "turn-right",
              "polyline": Object {
                "points": "_g_bIzq~Gi@dCCFQz@Yv@a@t@Wb@IJGFUR",
              },
              "start_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.9216,
                "lng": -1.4724555,
              },
              "travel_mode": "WALKING",
            },
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
                "text": "0.1 km",
                "value": 111,
              },
              "duration": Object {
                "text": "2 mins",
                "value": 90,
              },
              "end_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.9234218,
                "lng": -1.4750736,
              },
              "html_instructions": "At the roundabout, take the <b>3rd</b> exit onto <b>68</b>/<b>Corporation St</b>/<b>Route 54</b>",
              "maneuver": "roundabout-left",
              "polyline": Object {
                "points": "{l_bI~}~GEAAAA?A@A?A?A?C@CDA??@CBAFA@?@AF[VGLiAl@MFMH",
              },
              "start_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.922543,
                "lng": -1.4743966,
              },
              "travel_mode": "WALKING",
            },
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
                "text": "0.1 km",
                "value": 105,
              },
              "duration": Object {
                "text": "1 min",
                "value": 81,
              },
              "end_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.9242042,
                "lng": -1.4756769,
              },
              "html_instructions": "At the roundabout, take the <b>2nd</b> exit onto <b>Full St</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Destination will be on the right</div>",
              "maneuver": "roundabout-left",
              "polyline": Object {
                "points": "kr_bIdb_HCICCCACAG@GDCFAFKFIDIFE@OPONMLa@h@?@",
              },
              "start_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.9234218,
                "lng": -1.4750736,
              },
              "travel_mode": "WALKING",
            },
          ],
          "travel_mode": "WALKING",
        },
      ],
      "traffic_speed_entry": Array [],
      "via_waypoint": Array [],
    },
  ],
  "overview_polyline": Object {
    "points": "_c{aIza`Hm@BEyHC_Ag@S?HsPw@eHgW_IkOmHcPoLiNgKxQwHvL{LxKuK`G{AqEJoPcU`AEJlAjCt@rAm@lCQz@Yv@y@xAQRUREAAAG@KFGNAHc@d@wAt@MHCIGEK?KLAFKFSLUR_AhA",
  },
  "summary": "",
  "warnings": Array [
    "Walking directions are in beta.    Use caution – This route may be missing sidewalks or pedestrian paths.",
  ],
  "waypoint_order": Array [],
}
```

Comment: have you tried just grabbing the routes array first and seeing how that looks? strenge you have no id's or anything to work with

Comment: Also what results are you getting from your previous attemps? Whats the console showing?

Comment: i have been getting same error [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'responseJson4.routes[0]].legs.steps')]

Comment: you need to handle the catch first then run it again and see what it says. You always need to handle errors in a fetch

Comment: .catch((error) => {
                            this.setState({
                                error: 'Something went wrong!' + error,
                            
                            })
                        })

Comment: ok i tried printing the routes array first and here is what i get i get this which i will paste above

Comment: ok its pasted above

Comment: the pattern looks like its inside legs and steps

Comment: yeah i see that. you could pull out the legs array then the steps array but that seems like alot of code for somethingyou could do in another way, perhaps with reduce. check out this article, specifically the part about accessing nested arrays: https://hackernoon.com/accessing-nested-objects-in-javascript-f02f1bd6387f

Comment: just for future reference, the long way is like this:` var info = responseJson3.routes[0].legs[0].steps[1];
                console.log(info);`

Comment: So you have access to it then?